# How to stop an event callback firing itself?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a Javascript event listener to trap clicks on the capture phase, perform an action, then repeat the click to trigger whatever code should normally happen.

```
var obj=document.getElementById('button');
obj.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Performing operation here');
    otherOperation('ajax', function(){
        obj.click();
    });
}, true);
```

Obviously this creates an infinite loop of operations. I thought this is the best approach because the operation requires a time delay and I can't continue event propagation until I get another callback.

Is there a way to detect the click was performed by my own callback function and therefore ignore it?

I had a theory to remove the event listener after operation is complete, but it would need to be added again in some circumstances which makes a lot of code.

Comment: Are you sure that your event handler will run before all the other previously attached handlers? Somehow I feel like this won't work

Comment: @hege_hegedus You're correct it's not a perfect solution at all! In my testing, though, when I catch the click on *capture* instead of bubble, it comes before all other plugins/things on the page for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky solution that would workn on most of the browsers would be to copy the button itself, hide or remove the original one, add a click handler to the new one, and call `button.click()` on the old one when neccessary.

Comment: Thanks! A great hack for ensuring my callback is first if others on the page are interfering. I wanted to accept adeneo's answer for simplicity but I need multi-browser support and this seems to be the way.

Answer (score 5):

It's trivial in modern browser (not IE or Safari), using [`event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted), wich is only true if the event was fired by a user action

```
var obj=document.getElementById('button');

obj.addEventListener('click', function(event){

   if ( event.isTrusted ) {

        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Performing operation here');
        otherOperation('ajax', function(){
            obj.click();
        });
   } else {
       // click triggered by javascript
   }

}, true);
```

If you have to support Safari and IE9 and above, you can dispatch the event with a custom argument

```
var obj = document.getElementById('button');

obj.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if ('trusted' in event && event.trusted === false) {
        // click triggered by javascript    
    } else {

        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Performing operation here');

        otherOperation('ajax', function() {
            var ev = new MouseEvent('click', { // create event
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': true
            });

            ev.trusted = false; // add custom data
            self.dispatchEvent(ev); // trigger event
        });

    }
}, true);
```

jQuery events adds somewhat similar functionality, where one could just check for the `originalEvent` to know if the event was triggered or not.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo that is indeed a great solution. Unfortunately I need support for IE/Safari and, if I understand the docs correctly, this would cause an infinite loop in IE :(

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, that there are two operations. 1. 'Other Operation' triggered as Async call 2. 'Normal' operation.

Normal operation can be triggered either as the call back inside the buttons listener or it can be called separately by any other means. How about the below solution to this?

```
var obj=document.getElementById('button');
obj.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Performing operation here');
    otherOperation('ajax', function(){
        normalOperation();
    });
}, true);

function normalOperation() {
  //normal operation to be happened for click
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rajbharath for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately the "normal operation" script is hard-coded onto the button's "onClick" property and I am not able to change this (I am writing a plug-in for a core script).